# Issues with topbar of sites I'm not participating in

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, firefox

For sites I'm not a member of there are two issues with the top bar after.

**Problem 1:**

Logo cut off and white space on the right

[image]

I don't see this problem on sites I'm logged into:

[image]

**Problem 2:**

When I scol down on sites I'm not logged into the headline vanishes a tiny bit earlier than the search field. This leads to situations where the headline is already away, but the search field is still there:

[image]

Again, this does not happen on sites which I'm a member of.

I'm using Firefix 52 ESR

Comment: ESR has tons of design bugs, guess they just changed some basic stuff behind the scenes. Sorry, but personally I prefer SE to spend their time fixing bugs that affect the major browsers.